# Pandas merge results in missing column/data

Tags: pandas, merge

I have two excel files which contain table 1 and table 2 respectively.
Table 1 has user details and table 2 has employee details.
Both tables have a column 'Email Address'.

I want to perform `pd.merge` in order to generate a new table which should basically return the data that has user details for those who happen to be current employees by using email address as the key column.

To do that, I was using left join to merge table 1, table 2.

```
import pandas as pd

df_user = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx')
df_emp = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')

df_new = df_user.merge(df_emp, how='left')
#df_new = pd.merge(df_user, df_emp, how='left')
#df_new = pd.merge(df_user, df_emp, on='Email Address', how='left')

df_new.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

I tried above 3 merge code but neither of those return the full data. What I got is a table contains data from table 1 and but only headers of table 2. Weird thing is that I can't find column 'Email Address' in the part that only showing headers of table 2 in the new table. The part from table 1 shows column 'Email Address' though.

Can someone please explain what I did wrong here?

What I was expecting is that a new table contains data from table 1 and matched data from table 2 using 'Email Address' as the merge/vlookup method since email address is the unique key for user table and employee table.

Comment: Check the value of df_emp.info()

Comment: Reformatting column 'Email Address' (I made both columns to lower case) seems worked fine. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use merge on Email Address. I am not sure what data you want to preserve from either table. This will merge the tables when they match the email address.

```
import pandas as pd

df_user = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx')
df_emp = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')

df_new = pd.merge(df_user, df_emp, left_on='Email Address', right_on='Email Address', how='left')
```

Comment: thanks @iohans. just tried out what you suggested. it did not work. it actually returned only header from both files but no data in rows. Not sure why. What i want to achieve is all data from file 1 and matched data from file 2 which is the reason why i used left for merge. For example, in file 1, i have user John Doe and all details for his license detail including email address, and the new table should give me John's employee details e.g. cost centre, location etc. So that i can see John's full details in one table. I hope this will make sense.

Comment: Hmm. I updated the answer to add more specific options for the merge.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Tried the new code, still not working. This time I can get data from file 1 but only headers from file 2 which is the same result of what my code returned. And the email address column header is missing from file 2 part in the new table, this really confuse me. Is merge 'eating' the column which has been used for option on='column'?  Since both files have column 'Email Address', merge only return one 'Email Address' to the new table?

Comment: Here's where I would go next... Copy your first XSLX file and make one data change to it. Test these two new files. This is to make sure there are no formatting differences between the files.

Comment: It did give me a hint that the format may be the reason. I simplified my data to see the difference and re-formatting the email address using lowercase to both email column and now I can get the data. Thanks for the help.